# federated mysql query with a reserved word column name fails to run in Redhsift

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift, reserved-words, federated-queries

I have a remote connection into a mysql database from Redshift. Mysql table has a column year_month which is a reserved word in mysql and since this table is already populated and applications are using it, column name cannot be changed.

I tried backtick, double quotes - both are failing.

`` select id, `year_month` from updoc_mysql.apsetup; ``

Comment: Please provide more information such as table schema

Comment: RedShift uses doublequotes for identifiers. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html Apply them then look what query text is received by MySQL (in General Query Log). Maybe you'd use ```"`year_month`"``` or even `ANSI_QUOTES` SQL Mode to be set..

Comment: @Akina - I tried "`year_month`" and I get the error: ERROR: column "`year_month`" does not exist. I can not set ANSI_QUOTES since I am running my queries as a federated user accessing the remote mysql.

Comment: Have you tried the syntax which I provide - with both doublequotes and backticks? If none works than enable general log and obtain SQL codes received by MySQL for all syntax variations. *and I get the error* - NEVER shorten the message error! Provide complete text (add to question text as an update, format as code), from first to last char.

Comment: @Akina - I tried all combinations of double quotes and backticks and nothing is working. Please remember these are queries run on an external mysql database from redshift. I do not have any access directly in mysql and I have reached out to the concerned person to enable logging and provide me feedback. Nothing has been done so far. I was hoping someone would have got this issue resolved.